# is there any android dynamic treeview like c# devExpress treeview

Tags: android, treeview, expandablelistview

I want to create dynamic treeview. But the levels of tree unknown. it's up to database. 
So expandable listview not work for me, 
is there any treeview example like below type in android ?

```
A...
 ->b...
 ->b...
 ->b...
    ->c..

A..
 ->b..
    ->c..
        ->d..
        ->d..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpandableListView` is for sure something to look into, but may not expose enough functionality though.

Having said that: on a mobile device it may not be a good idea to show an arbitrarily deep tree, as the user a) may have issues selecting the nodes and b) may loose himself in navigation due to the reduced screen estate.

Especially for a) keep in mind that a touch point is not a few pixels like when you click with a mouse, but depending on screen resolution an area of 20x20-80x80 pixels.

Comment: my application use in 10'' tablet. it's not problem for me. My aim is showing stock groups for sellers. Its unknown level, because every firm create your groups itself.
 For example; 

   `Electronics 
     ->Computer
        ->Notebooks 
             -> intel i5
                  ->...( maybe another level)
             -> intel i3
        ->Desktop` 
if tree is not avaible for this stuation, what do you suggest for me ?